Complete language in P∪{C,D}
given: C is a NP-coNP language, D is a coNP-NP language and P is the known time-complexity class.
assumption: NP ≠ coNP.
I need to determine if exists a language B, such that:
a. B ∈ P∪{C, D}.
b. for every language A in the class above, there is a polynomial time reduction from it to B.
I think there is no such language because, for every option of B to be such language, the assumption is contradicted - but I can't write a detailed answer as to why this is happening. If I had known that either C or D (or both) are complete languages in their department, it would be pretty straightforward to prove what I need, but I know no such thing.

What do you meant by "in the department above"?

the department P∪{C, D}

We usually call these classes. Is there a reason for not using latex? For example, instead of writing ∈, you can write \in between two dollars, and it appears as $\in$.

The reason is that I'm not familiar at all with latex, and I forgot the word, so I used what I did remember.

Please [edit] your post to clarify it rather than responding in the comments.  We want the question to stand on its own and make sense without people having to read the comments to understand what is being asked.

I intended to do it but forgot, thank you!

There is no need to assume that $C$ and $D$ are complete w.r.t their classes. Specifically, the contradiction follows from the fact that if $B$ exists, then some class collapses:
assume towards contradiction that such $B$ exists. Then, we distinguish between three cases:

$B\in \text{P}$: this is impossible as it would imply that $ C\leq_p B $, and therefore, $C \in \text{P}$.

$B = C$: this is impossible as it would imply that $D \leq_p B$, and since $C\in \text{NP}$, we would get that $D$ is in $\text{NP}$ as well.

$B = D$: similar to the above case, and I leave it to you.


